# Два Listbox - связать

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ранее был мой вопрос о связи двух `Listbox` между собой, немного поколдовал и получилось их прибиндить и реализовать одновременную прокрутку.
Очередной вопрос -- в поле ввода вводим текст, поиск в 1 `Listbox` и вывод, но второй `Listbox` не производит сортировку вслед за первым.
Например, в первом `Listbox` названия городов, во втором -- фамилии. Вводим Новосибирск, остаются только строчки Новосибирск, второй `Listbox` не получается прибиндить.

Кусочек кода:

```py
scrollbar = Scrollbar(Form3)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                
listbox_values = Variable()        
listbox = Listbox(Form3, listvariable=listbox_values, font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
listbox1 = Listbox(Form3, font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
        
def check_input(_event=None):
    value = entry.get().lower()

    if value == '':
        listbox_values.set(lst)
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)               

        listbox_values.set(data)

def on_change_selection(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()            
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        var1.set(data)
        check_input()       

def scrolllistbox1(eventt):
    listbox1.yview_scroll(int(-4*(eventt.delta/120)), "units")
    listbox1.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_change_selection)

def scrolllistbox(eventt):            
    listbox.yview_scroll(int(-4*(eventt.delta/120)), "units")
    listbox.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_change_selection)

entry = Entry(Form3)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox1.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.bind("<MouseWheel>", scrolllistbox1)                
listbox1.bind("<MouseWheel>", scrolllistbox)          

with open('reg.txt', 'r') as file:
    lst = file.readlines() 
for item in lst:
    listbox.insert('end', item)

with open('reg1.txt', 'r') as file:
    lst1 = file.readlines() 
for item1 in lst1:
    listbox1.insert('end', item1)

listbox.pack(expand=1, fill="both", side="left")        
listbox1.pack(expand=1, fill="both", side="left")           
listbox_values.set(lst)
```

Comment: Почему не импортируется tkinter?